# Qual diferença entre falha, defeito e erro?

Tags: terminologia, engenharia-de-software

No desenvolvimento de software com frequência ocorrem problemas na aplicação já pronta, alguns termos usados para classifica-los são: **falha**, **defeito** e **erro**.

- Qual a diferença de um termo para o outro?
- Esses termos estão definidos em alguma ISO ou similar?
- Existe algum outro termo relevante que denote essa situação de "resultado não esperado/problema"?

Comment: Falha é dos outros, defeito já veio assim e erro eu não cometo :D

Comment: @bigown defeito ou vício oculto? haha

Comment: Se for ISO é não conformidade :)

Comment: Os conceitos de error, failure, fault são muitos utilizados em testes de software, mas nunca pensei nessas "palavras" fora desse contexto.

Comment: @Randrade isso, acha que faltou a tag de teste?

Comment: @rray Eu realmente fiquei em dúvida se possui um outro significado sem ser em testes. Mas, se a dúvida é sobre essa área mesmo, eu acho que caberia sim.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento "defeito" aqui em Portugal é igual ao Brasil. Indica "imprecisão, irregularidade, falha, incorreção, imperfeição, inexatidão, erro, deficiência, deformação". "Por defeito" é que é usado como equivalente a "default".

Comment: @ramaral entendi, obrigado :)

Answer (score 25):

> Qual a diferença de um termo para o outro?

- **Falha**: É um comportamento inesperado do software. Uma falha pode ter sido causada por diversos erros, mas alguns erros podem nunca causar uma falha. [Exemplo prático](http://www.devmedia.com.br/testes-de-software-entendendo-defeitos-erros-e-falhas/22280): Houve um retorno de um valor não esperado, como `null`, isso é um erro, e por causa desse `null` ocasionou uma falha no sistema.
- **Defeito**: É uma inconsistência no software, algo que foi implementado de maneira incorreta. Ele ocorre em uma linha de código, como uma instrução errada ou um comando incorreto. O defeito é a causa de um erro, porém se uma linha de código que contém o defeito nunca executar, o defeito não vai provocar um erro.
- **Erro**: Erro humano produzindo resultado incorreto. O erro evidencia o defeito, ou seja, quando há diferença entre o valor obtido e o valor esperado  constitui um erro.

Em resumo, se por engano você faz um `if` errado, causa um defeito, que quando for ativado vai produzir um erro. Se esse erro for propagado até a saída do software constituirá uma falha.

> Esses termos estão definidos em alguma ISO ou similar?

Sim. [ISO/IEC/IEEE 29119](http://www.softwaretestingstandard.org/) Software Testing, mas especificamente na IEEE 829 Test Documentation.

> Existe algum outro termo relevante que denote essa situação de
>   "resultado não esperado/problema"?

Sim. Incidente ou anomalia que é o mesmo que defeito. Na prática tudo de errado que acontece a gente chama de "bug".

Referências:

- [Testes de software - Entendendo Defeitos, Erros e falhas](http://www.devmedia.com.br/testes-de-software-entendendo-defeitos-erros-e-falhas/22280)
- [Fundamentos de Teste de Software](http://ava.nac.softex.br/pluginfile.php/598/mod_resource/content/2/Aula1.pdf)
- [Qual a diferença entre Defeitos, Erros e Falhas em um software?](http://alexpagernet.blogspot.com.br/2014/05/qual-diferenca-entre-defeitos-erros-e.html)

Answer (score 3):

**Falha**: Imagine a segunite linha de código:

if (x < 10):{
    //TODO
}

O programador esqueceu de colocar o "=", no caso o código correto seria:

if(x <**=** 10){
   //TODO
}

ou seja, falha, é qualquer interferência externa que comprometa o fluxo do software, seja interferência humana (programador esqueceu algo), um raio, uma bomba...

O **Erro** acontece quando essa falha é notada, ou seja, quando em um teste, a falha for ativada! Digamos que nos testes, x = 10, e é esperado que entre dentro da condição.

O **defeito** acontece quando o comportamento do erro for notado, então está com defeito!

É um ciclo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]